# Adding Fields/ Columns to oc_product_description Table, Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart2.3

Background: Added some new columns in oc_product_description (I added some key product features and alternative name for ebay listing, so I can generate the product data into a template to use on ebay listings, whilst keeping and using the code on the opencart website..)

Problem: that when I save the product in opencart it deletes the data I just entered into the table, because it uses a Delete and then Insert function (by the looks of it?) in admin/model/catalog/product.php approx line 140. Which uses the $data['product_descriptions'] array which comes about in admin/controller/catalog/product.php approx line 765.. but here there are 3 possibilities.. either from the post or from a get function, or a new array..
I added hidden fields to the admin/view/catalog/product_form.php but what's going on here doesn't make it through to the table in the end..

I also added the new fields to the getProductDescriptions() function and directly to the $data array just as the other fields were already..

Please don't send me off to look up MVC models..Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: that I had used the wrong name and value in the hidden fields..I obviously wasn't giving it much thought when I merely wrote:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name_ebay" value="<?php echo $entry_name_ebay; ?>">
```

In actual fact what was required was:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][name_ebay]" value="<?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['name_ebay'] : ''; ?>">
```

I hope this post has offered some reminders or hints concerning Adding Your Own Fields to Opencart's Product Description Table, and using them in the admin
Take note mostly of:
i) use of language id in the view
ii) the delete, insert (instead of update) in model
iii) the change from post to $data array in controller

Furthermore, I did notice that the delete line,

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

Seems to delete the record with this product id?? but without regard to language id?.. I'll have to look into whether this deletes the translated versions on a multi-lingual site of the products in the product_description table..?